# How can I make environment variables "exported" in a shell script stick around?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, environment-variables

I have multiple Amazon EC2 accounts and want to quickly be able to switch variables, such as `$EC2_HOME`, using a script.

I have have a shell script set up like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export EC2_HOME=/home/me/.ec2
echo $EC2_HOME
```

When I run the script I know that `EC2_HOME` is set, but I thought that using `export` would make the variable stick around after the script completed. It does not, as running `echo $EC_HOME` does not show anything.

I know this must be very rudimentary Linux scripting knowledge, but I don't know it. I tried looking for related questions without luck - so my apologies if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You should source your script, with

```
. ./script
```

or

```
source ./script
```

Comment: the reason is that your script spawns a new shell process as a child of the current shell. Any environment changes you make in the child process *cannot* affect the parent. When you use `.` or `source`, you are not spawning a new child process, you are running the commands in the current shell.

Comment: @glennjackman I have a similar problem and I have tried your solution but it logs me off from shell when I do `.` or `source`. Why is this happening ?

Comment: @Patryk: maybe your script has an `exit` statement, so it is not suitable to be sourced.

Comment: While `source ./script` works completely fine, `sudo source ./script.sh` says `sudo: source: command not found`. How can I do this using sudo?

Comment: @71GA: depending on compilation preferences for `sudo` and depending on configuration settings in `/etc/sudoers` you can or cannot preserve your environment when running commands with `sudo`. I suggest you to try to source your script, and then run `sudo` with `-E` option to preserve the environment. If it does not work, I suppose there is very little you can do.

Comment: @71GA, the factual answer to this is: You can't use `sudo` to run a shell built-in (and it wouldn't make any sense if you could).

Comment: There could also be problems with script arguments - some scripts rely heavily on `$0` param - which should be the script name, but here it is the shell it self. It can produce some unexpected behavior `(dirname $0)`...

Answer (score 50):

When you run a script it gets its own shell and its own environment, which disappear again as soon as the script is finished. To keep the environment variables around, source the script into your current shell:

```
$ source ./a.sh
```

or equivalently (but a little more portably) use the [POSIX dot command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot):

```
$ . ./a.sh
```

Then the definitions will be put into your current shell's environment and be inherited by any programs you launch from it.

To be closer to running a script, `. a.sh` will find a.sh by searching the directories in the `PATH` environment variable.

---

<sub>There are some subtleties in how these behave, and whether `.` and `source` are the same (or present at all). `. ./a.sh` will definitely behave the same in every POSIX-compatible shell, but `source` and `.`, and `. a.sh` and `. ./a.sh`, can vary. For Bash [`source` and `.` are the same](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-source) in all cases; for [zsh `source` always checks the current directory first](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html); ksh is essentially similar.</sub>

<sub>If the script name is given as a path (containing a `/`), that path is used directly in all cases. The most portably reliable thing to do is `. ./script` or `. /path/to/script`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Just for record.

If you want run script from internet which exports env to system

you can use following format

```
source <(curl -s -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamwwc/wwcdocker/master/install.sh)
```

For example:

```
source <(curl -s -L https://example.com/install.sh)
```

Comment: Looks dangerous but useful if you trust that script!

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
exec ./script
```

The exec command runs the script in the current shell without starting non interactive shell.

Comment: This will replace the shell with the script. i.e. you loose your shell after running this command