# Shell script executing in the terminal but not from shell script file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make variables “exported” in a bash script stick around?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/how-can-i-make-variables-exported-in-a-bash-script-stick-around)

I have a problem with executing script from file. When I type in command line

`PATH=$PATH:/home/`

then `PATH` is changed appropriately. But when I execute this file :

```
#!/bin/sh
#provided by me

PATH=$PATH:/home/
echo "done"
exit 0
```

`done` is printed but `PATH` is not changed. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environmental variable changes apply to the current process and any subsequent children, but not to parent processes.  So if you run a script, it cannot affect the environmental variables of the shell that ran it.  You need to `source` the script using the `.` shell builtin.  I.e.

```
. /path/to/script
```

This causes the current shell to execute the commands in the file instead of running a subprocess.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how should I do this since now I am writing my script, putting it in `/etc/init.d/` and running `update-rc.d myScriptName defaults`. Or in other words: is there better way to permanently change `$PATH` ?

Comment: Set PATH in /etc/profile.  This will affect sh, ksh and bash users.  /etc/zprofile is the file to use for zsh users.

Comment: I have tried `source` and `.` but it logs me off from chell. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Remove the `exit 0` from the script.  It is telling your shell to exit, which is not what you want.