# How to loop through xargs where each script uses a common env variable

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, xargs

Is it possible to initiate 10 of the same shell scripts which also initiate more copies, and have them all use the same env variable?

For example:

**script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
export COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1));
echo $COUNTER;
sleep 5;
/script.sh
```

using `xargs -P 10 script.sh` results in each instance creating its own scope, rather than sharing the same $COUNTER variable

I'm essentially trying to deploy `script.sh` 10 initial times, and then when each one completes, it automatically executes `script.sh` again, only this time with the newly incremented `$COUNTER` variable.

I've asked a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106965/env-variables-in-relation-to-xargs-loops/106968?noredirect=1#106968) here, and now understand why my previous method does not work, I'm extremely interested in learning what the best way to actually accomplish this will be.

Comment: No, a process can't alter a variable in the parent process.

Comment: Yea, I've (unfortunately) been made aware of this. I'm really interested to see what the best way to accomplish a task like this will be!

Comment: Use a language that supports shared variables in threads. Even then, you will have a ton of race conditions. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm cycling through a list, and want to pass one line to a script. each time the script finishes it should start itself up again using the "next" line.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It can limit the number of jobs spawned in varying ways ( `--jobs 10` for your application)  and also has a job number (`{#}`) that can be passed as an argument to the script.

As Ole commented, the following should work:

```
find . -type f | parallel -j10 my_script {#} {}
```

Comment: find . -type f | parallel -j10 my_script {#} {}

Comment: @OleTange, thank you for comment (included in answer for better visibility). And thanks for writing `parallel` in first place.

Answer (score 1):

IPC might be another approach. You can create a shared memory segment that will provide you with a locking mechanism where each process can then update the value stored here. This is not a file on the filesystem, it's a section of memory that is designated for this purpose.

You can read more about IPC via the `man ipcs` man page.

#### References

- [10 IPCS Command Examples (With IPC Introduction)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/ipcs-command-examples/)