# How to declare some aliases dynamically in zsh?

Tags: zsh, quoting, alias, cd-command

I would like to declare a few shortcut commands to switch between my various coding projects, so I have come up with the following script.

```
projects=$(ls -d ~/Workspace/*/)
prefix="/Users/myuser/Workspace/"
for f in $projects
do
        temp=${f#$prefix}
        temp=${temp/%\//}
        c="alias $temp='cd $f'"
        echo $c
        eval $c
done
```

I put that in a file called `.workspace-shotcuts.sh` in my homefolder, then I `chmod +X .workspace-shotcuts.sh` it. 
when I run it, using `./.workspace-shotcuts.sh` I get

```
alias project1='cd /Users/myuser/Workspace/project1/'
alias project2='cd /Users/myuser/Workspace/project2/'
```

in the console. But the aliases are not declare (`zsh: command not found: project1`).

Also at the end of my `.zshrc` file I have added `/bin/sh .workspace-shotcuts.sh`, which gives the same output, but still no aliases.

Any body can tell me what I am missing? I would like to point out that I am not a great *nix user, so you might have to ELI5 some things to me.

EDIT:

I was suggested to use `source` instead, which I have done, but here is the error messages I get:

```
(eval):2: permission denied: /Users/myuser/Workspace/project1/
(eval):3: permission denied: /Users/myuser/Workspace/project2/    
(eval):4: permission denied: /Users/myuser/Workspace/project3/
(eval):5: permission denied: /Users/myuser/Workspace/project4/
(eval):6: permission denied: /Users/myuser/Workspace/project5/
(eval):7: permission denied: /Users/myuser/Workspace/project6/
(eval):8: permission denied: /Users/myuser/Workspace/project7/
(eval):9: no such file or directory: /Users/myuser/Workspace/project1=cd /Users/myuser/Workspace/project1/\n/Users/myuser/Workspace/project2/\n/Users/myuser/Workspace/project3/\n/Users/myuser/Workspace/project4/\n/Users/myuser/Workspace/project5/\n/Users/myuser/Workspace/project6/\n/Users/myuser/Workspace/project7/
```

What is happening? Is there some special permission I need to give my script?

Comment: I think the problem may be that variables set or exported in a script cannot  alter the calling (parent) environment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604462/setting-environment-variable-in-shell-script-does-not-make-it-visible-to-the-she for example.

Comment: @Michael Homer, @cuonglm, @msw ... I have tried `source`, I do not think it fixed much.

Comment: I don't know `zsh`, but it looks like you're having a problem with a difference between `zsh` and `/bin/sh`.  Try running `zsh .workspace-shotcuts.sh`; it will probably fail the same as the `source` command.  Then look at `zsh` documentation to figure out what you need to change to get it to work in `zsh`.  Then `source .workspace-shotcuts.sh` should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of your problems is that you executed your snippet in a separate shell process, which has no effect on the parent shell. It's the same problem as in [How can I make environment variables "exported" in a shell script stick around?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/how-can-i-make-variables-exported-in-a-bash-script-stick-around). You need to use the [`source`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-_002e) builtin (also avilable under the name `.`) to execute the script inside the same shell.

```
source ~/.workspace-shotcuts.sh
```

Another problem is that you're trying to parse the output of `ls`. [Don't do that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In shells such as sh and bash, you can get away with it because writing `$projects` outside of quotes splits the value at the newlines that separates the file names. Except that it doesn't actually work: for example, if the file names contain spaces, they will be broken into space-separated pieces. In a shell script, don't parse the output of `ls`, use wildcards instead. This is rather straightforward in zsh.

```
projects=(~/Workspace/*/)
for f in $projects; do …
```

What you're doing next is rather convoluted. You don't need `eval` here; using it only sets you up for quoting mishaps. Since you're using zsh, you can use the [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) `t` to extract the last component of a path, without reaching for string manipulation constructs: `$f:t`. In case the file name contains special characters, you should protect them, and again zsh makes this easy thanks to the [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) `q`: `${(q)f}` gives you a quoted filename that you can use in the alias definition.

```
projects=(~/Workspace/*/)
for f in $projects
do
  alias $f:t="cd ${(q)f}"
done
```

---

But in fact, **you're just reinventing [`cdpath`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-cdpath) plus [`auto_cd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fCD)**. Scratch all that and use

```
setopt auto_cd
cdpath+=~/Workspace
```

The `auto_cd` option lets you type a directory name to change into it, without having to type `cd ‍` before it. The `cdpath` is an array of directory prefixes that `cd foo` tries if there isn't a subdirectory called `foo` in the current directory.

---

In case bash users see this thread: the alias method would be

```
projects=(~/Workspace/*/)
for f in "${projects[@]}"; do
  f=${f%/}
  alias ${f##*/}="cd '${f//\'/\'\\\'\'}'"
done
```

and the `CDPATH` method would be

```
CDPATH=$CDPATH:$HOME/Workspace
shopt -s autocd
```

Comment: I'd move the `cdpath` suggestion into a TL;DR line at the top of the post :)

Comment: Also, I think you're missing `setopt AUTOCD` (for `zsh`) and `shopt -s autocd` (for `bash`) to complete the idea of using a directory name as an alias for changing to that directory.

Comment: @chepner Duh, thanks. After all these years on autocd, I tend to forget that it's one of the things that made me switch to zsh back when bash didn't have it.

Comment: sorry for the accepted answer arriving late