# Why running eval from cli works, but running script with eval inside it, it doesn't?

Tags: linux, eval

Why when I run `eval $(keychain --quiet ~/.ssh/id_rsa)` from cli it works, but if I try to do same from the script it doesn't work and $SSH_AUTH variables are not present?

Comment: Do you mean that `$SSH_AUTH` is empty once the script has terminated? If so, then I'm not surprised. A script can not modify the environment of its parent shell.

Comment: is there anyway I can export those variable from the script?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/how-can-i-make-environment-variables-exported-in-a-shell-script-stick-around

Comment: Error  `$SSH_AUTH` variables are not present -- I read the whole question, it is not there.