# Pass Variable from inside a shell script to be used outside

Tags: shell

I have a shell script that has multiple variables , I would like to export a specific variable from the script to a command I want to run after the shell script is executed

```
#!/bin/sh 
a=10
b=20
c=a+b
echo $a
export a
```

and the command I want to run is `echo $a`

Comment: Just to make sure, did you check out this Q already? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/how-can-i-make-environment-variables-exported-in-a-shell-script-stick-around?rq=1

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1376604/432690

Comment: I guess the script is the first four lines only? This is not going to work unless you source it (`source` or `.`).