Set environment variables in a python script and use them in a chained call
I would like to set a couple of environment variables in a Python script, then use said environment variables in a chained call.
For example, a python script called set_env.py:
os.environ["MY_VAR"] = "cool value"

And then in bash
python ./set_env.py && echo "$MY_VAR"

Is such a thing possible?
I've tried to use the os.environ, os.system using export MY_VAR=..., but none of them seem to work.

This is in general not possible: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/how-can-i-make-environment-variables-exported-in-a-shell-script-stick-around. You can get the Python script to execute the other commands instead.

What muru said. But can you explain why you want this? I mean, if you are setting shell variables, why do you even want to do it with a script in a different language? Why not use a shell script that you can source?

You can do it with export MY_VAR="cool value" for any shell environment also.

Since python runs in a child process of the shell it can't directly alter the shell's environment variables. However, your python script can output proper shell commands that can be evaluated in the shell.
$ python ./set_env.py
MY_VAR="x y z";MY_VAR2="a b c"

Then use the output of your python script like this:
$ eval "$(python ./set_env.py)" && echo "$MY_VAR"
x y z

